# Java getConnection to Oracle DB on UNIX crashed or takes much longer than on Windows

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection

I actual have a big problem! I open a connection to a oracle database with "DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)".
On UNIX machines (currently on a VM), the problem occurs that 99% of the time it needs minutes till the function return a connection. I increased the connection timout of oracle so that I don't get a SQLException, but it needs up to 3 Minutes to get a connection. On my windows machine the connection is returned in under 1 second.

telnet to server + port works, ping is sucessfully, traceroute looks good. I also tried from several VMs or on different databases on different physical machines.

I run the actual JDBC Driver "ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar".

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Can you share you JDBC connection URL?

Comment: It is: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.100:1523:sid" - just edited the sid and the ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time we figured out the problem. The Oracle JDBC driver blocked at the point where a unique id was read. After setting the VM Argument

***-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom***

we could gurantee to always receive a uniqueid in an adequate time. The default /dev/random unfortunately just generates a uniqueid if the machine has enough entropy, which is often missing on virtual machines.

Maybe this helps some of you folks one day.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit strange but it could be a REVERSE DNS problem.

If you Oracle server is on unix, try the following:

```
$ host IP_ADDRESS_OF_WIN_MACHINE
$ host IP_ADDRESS_OF_LINUX_MACHINE
```

See if there is something different on the two name resolutions. If there is, then it might be the case that trying to do a reverse DNS lookup on the LINUX IP is taking too long.

It's happened to me.

Comment: The Oracle Server runs on Windows. The Names are resolved correctly. I also tried to use the JDBC connection URL with the hostname and the ip.

Comment: It's not a problem of NAME RESOLUTION. It's probably a problem of **REVERSE** NAME RESOLUTION.

Comment: You can try with **tcpdump** on the server. To see the exact moment where the connection packet arrives with each configuration.

Comment: nslookup on the ip returns a name directly. Try tcpdump later.